# Exclusive locks for update and then insert not working

Tags: mysql, aws-lambda, transactions, locking, amazon-rds

We are experiencing some issues with the exclusive locks. We have the tables below:

```
mysql> desc journeys ;
+---------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| journey_id    | char(36)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| is_completed  | tinyint(1) | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| user_id       | char(36)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| created_at    | datetime   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| updated_at    | datetime   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| pack_id       | char(36)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| family_id     | char(36)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+---------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

mysql> desc packs ;
+---------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| pack_id       | char(36)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| is_published  | tinyint(1) | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| order         | int(11)    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| created_at    | datetime   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| updated_at    | datetime   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| family_id     | char(36)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+---------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

We also have those indexes:

```
+----------------------+------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table                | Non_unique | Key_name      | Seq_in_index | Column_name   | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+----------------------+------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| journeys |          0 | PRIMARY       |            1 | journey_id    | A         |          35 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| journeys |          1 |       pack_id |            1 |       pack_id | A         |          17 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| journeys |          1 | family_id     |            1 | family_id     | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| journeys |          1 | user_id       |            1 | user_id       | A         |           4 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+----------------------+------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

We have a AWS lambda function (in node.js) and the logic is like that:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ; 
START TRANSACTION;

(SELECT QUERY 1) SELECT `pack_id`, `is_published`, `order`, `family_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at` FROM `packs` AS `packs` WHERE `packs`.`family_id` = '6e9bdac8-1380-4e65-babc-be7858150bec' AND `packs`.`is_published` = true;

(SELECT QUERY 2) SELECT `journey_id`, `is_completed`, `user_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `pack_id`, `family_id` FROM `journeys` AS `journey` WHERE `journey`.`user_id` = '58411ec6-493b-4173-8649-569eb624d46c' FOR UPDATE;

// There is a bit of logic in node.js here to find the difference between the packs and the journeys depending on the pack_id
// For example, if we find 8 results in the first query and 0 results in the second query, we are finding the difference and we
// insert it in the journeys table in the query below. So we expect 8 entries into the journeys table after the insert.

INSERT INTO `journeys` (`journey_id`,`is_completed`,`user_id`,`created_at`,`updated_at`,`pack_id`,`family_id`) VALUES 
('032708d2-00e5-4933-b0d8-c53499b78a7c',false,'58411ec6-493b-4173-8649-569eb624d46c','2020-03-26 18:38:21','2020-03-26 18:38:21','004
7ebd6-129d-45e1-a347-41eda0ad1195','6e9bdac8-1380-4e65-babc-be7858150bec'),('75a11afd-1adf-4e5f-b44e-85e54421812b',false,'58411ec6-49
3b-4173-8649-569eb624d46c','2020-03-26 18:38:21','2020-03-26 18:38:21','1b42fa56-827b-442b-bc07-0be54843b8e6','6e9bdac8-1380-4e65-bab
c-be7858150bec'),('c12ab6ac-f5ec-423a-bffc-004292ca2f39',false,'58411ec6-493b-4173-8649-569eb624d46c','2020-03-26 
18:38:21','2020-03-26 18:38:21','80707835-6d7f-47a9-9da8-294ab6d14f92','6e9bdac8-1380-4e65-babc-be7858150bec'),('f4bdf022-2756-4ceb-a
8d0-065abcecc071',false,'58411ec6-493b-4173-8649-569eb624d46c','2020-03-26 18:38:21','2020-03-26 18:38:21','82061215-d24d-4012-b95c-a
e9ded725fa9','6e9bdac8-1380-4e65-babc-be7858150bec'),('d86f30e5-4e03-4638-b415-0a4340ab23b2',false,'58411ec6-493b-4173-8649-569eb624d
46c','2020-03-26 18:38:21','2020-03-26 18:38:21','ad1623cf-a357-47fa-8745-3c2ac7c40af6','6e9bdac8-1380-4e65-babc-be7858150bec'),('cfa
0e974-9ee5-424c-9ccc-c0a2c068309a',false,'58411ec6-493b-4173-8649-569eb624d46c','2020-03-26 18:38:21','2020-03-26 18:38:21','d6d61531
-88b2-4d44-8357-19e95c4ca379','6e9bdac8-1380-4e65-babc-be7858150bec'),('0faced86-29aa-429d-a763-c9d79898cebf',false,'58411ec6-493b-41
73-8649-569eb624d46c','2020-03-26 18:38:21','2020-03-26 
18:38:21','e6e737f8-d051-4b6f-b93a-765b6e39038b','6e9bdac8-1380-4e65-babc-be7858150bec');

COMMIT;
```

So the scenario is this:

- We are firing two API POST requests in parallel
- Two lambdas are running concurrently and they execute exactly the same logic above
- It seems that the lock in the SELECT QUERY 2 does not work. Quite often we end up with 16 entries into journeys table.
- We expect that only 8 entries should be in the journeys table because the first request will lock the rows, therefore the second request should wait for the first lock to be released. The first request inserts to the table commits and release the lock. Then the second request should access the journeys data but it will get the up to date results.

The strange thing is that when I open two terminals, I connect to the database and I execute the logic above, I can see that the second terminal waits for the first one to commit the transaction.

Any ideas about what are we missing?

Comment: I made a mistake in the copy/paste @Akina. Just updated the question.

Comment: You use SELECT .. FOR UPDATE which locks the rows for write until the end of transaction. If you want to allow these rows to be read by another threads then use FOR SHARE or LOCK IN SHARE MODE. And look at [Locking Reads](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html).

Comment: This is exactly what I want to avoid @Akina. I don't want to allow the rows to be read by another thread and that's why I'm using an exclusive lock. When they are executed within the lambda function though, it seems that the exclusive lock is not working and allows other threads to read exactly the same rows.

Comment: It seems that you need `SKIP LOCKED`. It causes locked records to be skipped from the output without the error or wait.